# How to set up xmr-stak-nvidia to solo mining

Tags: monerod, solo-mining

I tried to point it in `config.txt` to my localhost monerod but fails with

> 2017-09-07 00:52:32.560 [RPC0]  ERROR   net.http        contrib/epee/include/net/http_protocol_handler.inl:357  simple_http_connection_handler::handle_invoke_query_line(): Failed to match first line: 
> {"method":"login","params":"login":"4AQSkERTh6MPyUaoqCvwkdLQ19TZ7fgExJf9FWGTmYhrUjo9hWJzrQARzCJwrYxjgfgS7Kp1DWSwQHwzWwzABzF8L4PC2fa","pass":"","agent":"xmr-stak-nvidia/1.4.0"},"id":1}

Answer (score 1):

You can use monero-stratum for solo mining:

https://github.com/sammy007/monero-stratum

Answer (score 0):

You can also use my pool to SOLO mine:

> Gulf Coast Mining
>   https://mon.gulfcoastmining.com

Refer to the PORTS page for available connections.